# ubuntu 15 black screen after suspend think pad e440

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, suspend, hibernate

I installed ubuntu 15 but after screen time out or after  suspend I face black screen and I can do nothing except shut down using power button.

my graphic card is nvidia M 840 
I try almost all related recommendations from other related posts but it dose not work :(

Comment: just a funny question but do you have swap space available that matches or exceeds your ram capacity? try typing in: "free" in terminal to see what it says about swap compared to your ram

Comment: I have 6 gig ram ddr 3 and 4 gig swap

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug relating to the nvidia Version 346 drivers

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-346-updates/+bug/1454817

It seems that you might get it to work if you purge the nvidia drivers and use Nouveau driver instead or update the nvidia driver to a newer version.

The steps to do that: http://www.allaboutlinux.eu/remove-nouveau-and-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-15-04/

The info I placed below was based on an upgrade issue that I experienced and at the time I believe I completely misunderstood your issue.

I found this to be very helpful.  First you must make sure your swap is setup to save the current state onto swap and then resume.  It involves setting your fstab, grub, and initramfs files properly.  Please read the following carefully and completely.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Next you can follow this ubuntu help to test for and setup Hibernate:

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

I am on an old dual boot Sony Vaio 64 bit VGNFW250j that initially came with Vista, currently running Win 7 and Ubuntu 15.04 with a shared Data partition between the two.  I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 my system that was not previously setup as dual boot using UBetbootin Frugal Boot method.  The first thing after Ubuntu was installed I wondered about Hibernate.  I hope this information helps you :)

Comment: thanks for your answer . but it seems problem dose not relate to the swap memory  because I have this problem also with suspend and I think 6 gig RAM with 5 gig swap would be enough .

Comment: Your problem may be related to nvidia 346 drivers see top of my answer above.

Comment: thank you for your answer . now I have a problem which I'v posted as another question http://askubuntu.com/questions/661685/my-ubuntu-15-dose-not-boot-on-lenovo-e440-unsupported-brightness-interface . would you also help me on this problem

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: yes. also some times I can boot in generic mode. but some times I got the above error and after re starting and testing other kernel version upstart mode It would have  boot .  It would be nice if I could have your help on this topic : http://askubuntu.com/questions/661685/my-ubuntu-15-dose-not-boot-on-lenovo-e440-unsupported-brightness-interface